# Perl : version->parse with invalid input

Tags: perl, parsing, version

I have an array of version numbers that I have read in from the output of a terminal command, 
unfortunately a few of them are not valid (5.2.5_076_06-beta) to be used with version::parse, I have the output "Invalid version format (version required) at get_version.pl line 8." this corresponds to  the line containing version->parse($test); and the entire script terminates. How do I work around this?

```
use version;

my $cmd  =  "ls -l /nfs/install/ | awk '{print \$9}'";
my @vers = `$cmd`;

foreach my $test ( @vers ) {
    try { 
        version->parse($test);
    }
    catch
    {
        my $index = 0;
        $index++ until $vers[$index] eq $test;
        print $vers[$index];
        splice(@vers, $index, 1);

    }
}

my @sorted_vers = sort { version->parse( $a ) <=> version->parse( $b ) } @vers;

foreach my $version (@sorted_vers)
{
        print $version;
}
```

Comment: So how would you check 5.2.5_076_06-beta, $str =~ /^[a-zA-Z]+$/ ?

Comment: Also how is showing what its failing on not a minimal reproducible example. I have provided both the failing input, the code and the generated error. :-?

Comment: Please read [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/version) for 'TYPES OF VERSION OBJECTS'. The documentation does not mention support for 'alpha','beta' representation of version. Perhaps you have to write your own module or override exiting methods.

Comment: @PolarBear I could, or I can discard those like I am trying to do when the parse fails.

Comment: @Bob R -- then how you will compare two versions if you discard 'alpha','beta' parts? Your post does not give a full picture why you try to do it. What you do and what is your final goal?

Comment: You claim you're getting an exception from a try block, implying the try block doesn't do what it's suppose to be doing. So you're alleging a bug in some unstated module. What do you expect from us???

Comment: It's possible you attempted to use try/catch without using a module that provides it, like [Syntax::Keyword::Try](https://metacpan.org/pod/Syntax::Keyword::Try). try/catch is not (yet) a built-in feature, so attempting to use it leads to confusing errors because it gets parsed as [indirect object syntax](https://perldoc.pl/perlobj#Indirect-Object-Syntax).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [version](https://perldoc.pl/version) module is for parsing Perl module versions, which have a [very specific format](http://blogs.perl.org/users/grinnz/2018/04/a-guide-to-versions-in-perl.html). For your task of sorting arbitrary non-Perl versions, try [Sort::Versions](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Versions).

```
use Sort::Versions;
my @sorted_vers = sort versioncmp @vers;
```

Comment: This with your above comments where very helpful, thank you very much.

This with your above comments where very helpful, thank you very much.

"It's possible you attempted to use try/catch without using a module that provides it, like Syntax::Keyword::Try. try/catch is not (yet) a built-in feature, so attempting to use it leads to confusing errors because it gets parsed as indirect object syntax."